# putc to print string to word in separate line C

Tags: c

i wanna print string to each word in each line .it looks like putc not working and why i can not use putchar in c programming language ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main() {
  char s[50];
  int i, len;
  printf("\enter string : ");
  gets(s);
  len = strlen(s);
  i = 0;
  while (i<len) {
    while (s[i] == ' ' && i<len)
      i++;
    while (s[i] != ' ' && i<len)
      putc(s[i++], stdout);
    putc('\n', stdout);
  }
  getch();
}
```

Comment: What is it that is not working?  Did you get an error message?  What behavior are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing *massively* wrong with your code, other than:

- the use of non-standard features like `conio.h` and `getch`;
- the use of unsafe functions (which tend not to matter in classwork that much);
- the wrong order for conditions in your `while` statements, which may cause undefined behaviour.

Hence, this code appears to do what you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    char s[50];
    int i, len;
    printf("enter string : ");
    gets(s);
    len = strlen(s);
    i = 0;
    while (i<len) {
        while (i < len && s[i] == ' ')
            i++;
        while (i < len && s[i] != ' ')
            putc(s[i++], stdout);
        putc('\n', stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, it's not that clean, a professional coder would tend to opt for more modularisation and worthwhile comments, something along the lines of the following. First, some general functions for skipping spaces and echoing words:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static char *skipSpaces (char *pStr) {
    // Just throw away spaces, returning address of first non-space.

    while (*pStr == ' ')
        pStr++;
    return pStr;
}

static char *echoWord (char *pStr) {
    // If at end of string, say so.

    if (*pStr == '\0')
        return NULL;

    // Echo the word itself.

    while ((*pStr != '\0') && (*pStr != ' '))
        putchar (*pStr++);

    // Then skip to start of next word (or end of string).

    pStr = skipSpaces (pStr);

    // Return new pointer.

    return pStr;
}
```

Then, with that done, the main program becomes a lot easier to understand:

```
int main (void) {
    // Get string from user in a more safe manner.

    char str[50];
    printf("Enter string: ");
    fgets (str, sizeof (str), stdin);

    // Remove newline if there.

    size_t len = strlen (str);
    if ((len > 0) && (str[len-1] == '\n'))
        str[len-1] = '\0';

    // Start with first real character.

    char *pStr = skipSpaces (str);

    // Process words and space groups (adding newline) until at end of string.

    while ((pStr = echoWord (pStr)) != NULL)
        putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```